# Enable function field in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

How can we enable the function field as circled in red in the screenshot below? I cannot find it in my Power BI Desktop. I am using DirectQuery.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you are referring to the Formula Bar.

The formula bar is only visible when you are working with DAX, i.e. creating/editing a measure or a column in a table.

Create a new measure or select an existing measure in the field picker on the right of the screen, and the formula bar will show.